# The method onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem) of type Home must override a superclass method

Tags: android, overriding

I get this message on the following code:

```
public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.x:
            Log.i(Home, "klick");

        case R.id.y:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And I always get this error:

> The method onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem) of type Home must override a
>   superclass method

I've searched all round the internet, there were some posts on stackoverflow, BUT!
My compiler is set to 1.6 and there is no exception for my project.

Why must it override a superclass method? Isn't this method a superclass method, I use super.onOptions...?

I want to have a @Override because I have seen it somewhere and my code doesn't seem to work without.

This is my first question here, so please don't be hard if I forgot something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **onOptionsItemSelected(..)**

You are missing the 's', you have onOptionItemSelected(..)

Comment: You are welcome. That is why @Override is so useful. It spots typos for you. Otherwise you would spend ages trying to find out why what you thought was a valid callback method, never got triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why the compiler doesn't find the superclass method, but..this is the problem.

If you have annotate your method with @Override the compiler is trying to find the method in the superclass and it doesn't find it (perphaps, because, the first ocurrence of the method is  two or three classes before, not immediately before.

The solution: remove the @Override annotation. The compiler won't check the superclass method and your code will compile ok.

Your code will work fine without the annotation.

PD. Sorry for my awful english. ç

Upps. Its is true. The method is onOptionsItemSelected with a big 's'. That why your override annotation doesnt work, the compiler doesn't find the superclass method.